# Forcing inline div to go to the next line after certain amount of divs have been rendered

Tags: html, css

I have a container div with X amount of smaller container squares. So something like this:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="little-square"></div>
    <div class="little-square"></div>
    <div class="little-square"></div>

</div>
```

The little-square divs will be rendered iteratively by use of a handlebars template. What I want it to do is to have a maximum of four little-square divs per line. So if we approach this situation:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="little-square"></div>
        <div class="little-square"></div>
        <div class="little-square"></div>
        <div class="little-square"></div>
        <div class="little-square"></div>
        <div class="little-square"></div>

    </div>
```

Then the expected result should be four little-squares in the first line of the container div, and then two little-squares in the second line. I was thinking about having some sort of js code implementing 'if created div is fourth in line, then inject a br in this div to force the newline', but not too sure if that's even well looked upon.

Any suggestions on how to do this? What should I take into consideration when planning this effect? (css noob here. thanks for the help).

Comment: so just use bootstrap css classes to solve this problem and paricularly this question use bootstrap css class `col-lg-3` for four dive in one line and if u want to three div in one line then use `col-lg-4` for further info just visit this site http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution for this but you could hack it with `display: inline` on elements and `content: "\00000a"`, `white-space: pre`.

```css
.little-square {
  background: black;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  line-height: 65px;
}
.little-square:nth-child(4n):after {
  content: "\00000a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="little-square"></div>
  <div class="little-square"></div>
  <div class="little-square"></div>
  <div class="little-square"></div>
  <div class="little-square"></div>
  <div class="little-square"></div>
</div>
```